# How to fix shifted columns on histogram?

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I am building a histogram with number of days as the x axis, but the columns are shifted. I want to bin the data on months, or more exactly, 30-day intervals. For some reason, when generating this graph the columns are not the right size, and the bars end up shifting a lot, as shown in the picture:

[image: Histogram output]

The bins are hardcoded like this:

```
    var data = d3.layout.histogram()
        .bins(20)
        (values);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })])
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .tickValues([0,30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300,330,360,390,420,450,480,510,540,570,600])
        .orient("bottom");

    var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; });

    bar.append("rect")
        .attr("x", 1)
        .attr("width", x(data[0].dx) - 1)
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); });

    bar.append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".75em")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("x", x(data[0].dx) / 2)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return formatCount(d.y); });

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
```

What is the correct way to solve this issue?

Comment: It sounds like you would want to set the number of ticks to be the number of bins + 1 rather than hard code the actual tick values.

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff, I think that is not the problem, since I hard coded 20 bins and 21 ticks, so that should still work... any other ideas?

Comment: You haven't actually posted the code that draws the bars...

Comment: Also, the default range of the histogram layout is the extent of your values ([min, max]). It look like the min value in your values is more than 30 so that might result in a misalignment between your bins and your axis ticks.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks again, I just added the rest of the code, does that help?

Comment: @ScottCameron true, how do you fix the range in the range for the histogram?

Comment: You should be able to fix the range by fixing the domain of your x scale.

Comment: Yes, as @LarsKotthoff says, or you can also use the range function on the histogram layout to specify it the same as the domain you supply to the scale.  https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Histogram-Layout#wiki-range